# JMeter / AMQ - Substitute substring when reading strings from JSON file

Tags: json, scripting, jms, activemq-classic, jmeter

I've been bashing against a brick wall on this ever since Monday, when the customer told me that we needed to simulate up to 50,000 pseudo-concurrent entities for the purposes of performance testing. This is the setup. I have text files full of JSON objects containing JSON data that looks a bit like this:

```
{"customerId"=>"900", "assetId"=>"NN_18_144", "employee"=>"", "visible"=>false,
 "GenerationDate"=>"2012-09-21T09:41:39Z", "index"=>52, "Category"=>2...}
```

It's one object to a line. I'm using JMeter's JMS publisher to read the lines sequentially:

```
${_StringFromFile(${PATH_TO_DATA_FILES}scenario_9.json)}
```

from the  each of which contain a different scenario.

What I need to do is read the files in and substitute assetId's value with a randomly selected value from a list of 50,000 non-sequential, pre-generated strings (I can't possibly have a separate file for each assetId, as that would involve littering the load injector with 50,000 files and configuring a thread group within JMeter for each). Programatically, it's a trivial matter to perform the substitution but it's not so simple to do it in JMeter on the fly.

Normally, I'd treat this as the interesting technical challenge that it is and spend a few days working it out, but I only have the weekend, which I suspect I'll spend sleeping overnight in the office anyway.

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reading your assets, use a [CSV Data SetConfig](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) , I suppose assetId will be the variable name.

Modify your expression:

```
   ${_StringFromFile(${PATH_TO_DATA_FILES}scenario_9.json, lineToSubstitute)}
```

To do the substitution, add a [Beanshell sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) or [JSR223_Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)J (using groovy) and code the substitution:

```
   String assetId = vars.get("assetId");
   String lineToSubstitute = vars.get("lineToSubstitute");
   String lineSubstituted = ....;
   vars.put("lineSubstituted", lineSubstituted);
```

Comment: Thanks, man. I wish I could give you more than one upvote. I was using the JSR223 Preprocessor with groovy, but I didn't know how to access the variables, perform the substitution or read in the assetIds. You have saved my life.

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON body is always the same or you have little changes in it, you should:

- Use an HTTP Sampler with RAW POST Body
- Put the JSON body in it with variables for asset ids
- Put asset ids in CSV Data Set config

Avoid using ${_StringFromFile} as it has a cost.

If you need scripting , use JSR223 Post Processor with Script in external file + Caching (available since 2.8) so that script is compiled.

Comment: Oh, that's much simpler. Thanks again.